# Enviar a una Vista la lista de Clientes de mi base de datos

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

les comento que estoy haciendo una base de datos donde registro clientes. Y para la deshabilitación de un cliente utilizo borrado lógico, poniendo la propiedad de Habilitado = false al cliente.

Entonces, se me ocurrió, que cuando cargue mi vista Create.html, le pase a esa vista todos los clientes que tengo en la base de datos, para así en el momento en que estoy escribiendo el nombre de un cliente pueda verificar si se trata de un cliente deshabilitado y poder autocompletar las cajas de texto para poder automatizar el proceso y poder decirle al cliente "Acá está registrado como que antes ya utilizó el servicio, aparece x dirección y x telefono, ¿son correctos? ¿desea cambiarlos? "

Para mandar mi lista de clientes a la vista Create lo hago así:

```
// GET: Clientes/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        // enviamos la lista de clientes para poder verificar si se trata de una renovación de cliente antiguo
        return View(context.Clientes.ToList()); 
    }
```

Y en la vista luego tengo:

```
    @model IEnumerable<TiendaJuegos.Models.Cliente>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Registro";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<h3>Datos del nuevo cliente:</h3>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()



    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().RazonSocial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().RazonSocial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtRazonSocial" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().RazonSocial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Direccion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Direccion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtDireccion" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Direccion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Telefono, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Telefono, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtTelefono" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().Telefono, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().RUT, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().RUT, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtRut" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().RUT, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Registrar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Volver a la lista", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script type="text/javascript">

           var x = $('#txtRazonSocial');


            x.blur(function () {

                // acá va el codigo para verificar que lo escrito en el textbox txtRazonSocial se trata de un cliente deshabilitado y se autocompletan los demás textbox con los datos de ese cliente 

        });


    </script>
```

Se supone que el @model está bien, porque estoy diciendo que se trata de una lista de Cliente, y eso es lo que yo le mando a la vista.

Pero luego verán que tuve que recurrir a poner en los editores "model => model.FirstOrDefault().", porque daba error simplemente poner "model." ya que model es una lista no un cliente solo.

Sin embargo, aunque así con FirstOrDefault no da error, igualmente la vista se carga ya con los textbox completados por el primer Cliente de mi lista modelo.

Es que necesito indicarle al EditFor o al Validation lo que es 1 cliente, entonces uso FirstOrDefault, pero luego se ve que eso hace que se escriba en los textbox ese Primer cliente,  y no quiero esto ultimo.

Además de esto, lo más importante, es que no sabría como con javascript hacer la verificación de que se trata de un cliente deshabilitado para autocompletar los textboxs.

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Edu, para comenzar deberias tener 1 dato por el cual filtrar al cliente, ejemplo Razon Social, y tal vez, en vez de obtener toda la lista de clientes al principio, cuando se escriba la Razon Social, hacer un request con Ajax al controller y preguntar si existe cliente deshabilitado con esa razon social. Si existe, devuelves el objeto cliente, y completas los campos con los datos. El model pasaria a ser 1 solo cliente. Si te gusta esta idea, te formulo la respuesta mas completa

Comment: No sabía que se podia llegar al controller desde el javascript en mi vista Create.html, interesante. ¿Como hago ese request con Ajax?
No me queda muy claro igualmente a que te referís con "devolver" el objeto cliente, ¿ a la vista? ¿eso no implicaría volver a cargar la pagina? es que mi intención es no tener que cargar nuevamente la pagina de ser posible, por eso lo de enviar todos mis clientes. Pero sea como sea me interesa comprender lo que tienes pensado. Espero tal respuesta mas completa.

Comment: Te recomiendo al igual que @GonzaloPigni utilizar validation remota y no tener todos los clientes en la vista. Esa respuesta es la que propongo mas abajo. O sea modificar como esta armado lo que presentas pero con la misma funcionalidad

Answer (score 1):

Mis recomendaciones

- **TEMA 1: Que el modelo de Crear sea exactamente el modelo que estas
  creando** : Es decir este caso Cliente y no una lista de Clientes
- **TEMA 2:  Validar un "Texto" en base a una lógica de negocio con Remote
  Validation** : Idem a lo que te comentan con ajax, eso es lo que utiliza
  pero ya viene algunas ayudas en ASP.NET MVC para estas validaciones en el servidor

Vamos por parte

**TEMA 1: Que el modelo de Crear sea exactamente el modelo que estas
   creando**

Aquí como ya los tienes armado es un vista para create con Editor directamente con los valores del modelo que en tu caso debería ser

```
   @model TiendaJuegos.Models.Cliente
```

Es decir tendrías en la parte de Razón Social

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RazonSocial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RazonSocial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtRazonSocial" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RazonSocial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Y así con el resto de las propiedades de a clase Cliente (TiendaJuegos.Models.Cliente) que son las que se solicitan al momento de crear

Vamos a la parte que solicitas que es **VALIDAR!**

Si bien hay validaciones que se pueden hacer en el cliente, por ejemplo si es requerido, algún formato. No todas las validaciones son convenientes hacerlas en el cliente directamente hablando. Imagínate en solución propuesta que tengas 10 millones de clientes deshabilitados. Es prácticamente no performante por decirlo elegantemente obtener al momento de crear esos clientes y llevarlos hacia la vista. Solamente para verificarlo. Tendríamos una HTML o js bastante extenso, y seria muy lento transmitir dicho HTML.

**¿Cómo seria una forma de validar mas cercana a los datos?**

Es decir ¿cómo podríamos validar que no ingreso un valor que ya esta en la DB? Bueno llevar la validación lo mas cerca de la DB. Es decir ir hasta el servidor con el dato escrito en el input html de Razón Social. Incluso podrías allí

- Validar que el ingreso no corresponda con un texto de Razón Social de un cliente deshabilitado
- Validar que el ingreso de texto no corresponda con un cliente ya ingresado

Para eso podemos ir a la DB de la forma que ya lo tienes modelos/proveedores de EntityFramework con LINQ, procedimientos almacenados, directos con comandos al la DB.

Bueno supongamos que tienes un método en un controlador que sea

**TEMA 2: Validar un "Texto" en base a una lógica de negocio con Remote Validation**

Aquí es realizar una petición ajax a un método en el controlador, api, etc. Vamos a utilizar el atributo de validación [remote validation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1#remote-validation)

Podrías tener un método en el controlador de Cliente llamado ValidarRazonSocial que va al negocio y luego a la capa de datos (aquí pon en código necesario para validar en la DB que esa razón social que enviamos es valida)

```
public class ClienteController : Controller  {

public JsonResult ValidarRazonSocial(string razonSocial)
{
    var esValida = _clienteNegocio.ValidarRazonSocial(razonSocial);

    return Json(esValida, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
}
```

}

Tendremos que decorar el objeto cliente para que valide

```
[Remote("ValidarRazonSocial","Cliente", ErrorMessage="Ya esta utilizado el campo {0}")]
public string RazonSocial { get; set; }
```

Aquí es la configuración del código, ademas deberías ver en el appSettings que tengas en true estas configuraciones

```
<appSettings>  
   <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />  
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />  
</appSettings>
```

y que tengas en el javascript las librerias

- jquery
- jquery.validate
- jquery.validate.unobtrusive

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [Remote Attribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)
- [Remote Validation in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/remote-validation-in-asp-net-mvc/)
- [Remote Validation In MVC 5 To Check If UserName and Email Id Exists](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/remote-validation-in-mvc-5-to-check-if-username-and-email-id-exists/)
- Un ejemplo de [remote validation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1#remote-validation)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guia

Answer (score 0):

hola edu creo que deberías hacer todo eso desde el controlador, y como dice @Gonzalo Pigni
deberias tener algun dato para filtral o paginar para no enviar por ejemplo 1200 clientes al mismo tiempo.

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string 
 searchString, int? page)
{
 ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
 ViewBag.RazonSocialSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "RazonSocial_desc" : "";
 ViewBag.DireccionSortParm = sortOrder == "Direccion" ? "Direccion_desc" : "Direccion";

if (searchString != null)
{
   page = 1;
}
else
{
   searchString = currentFilter;
}

 ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

 var clientes = from c in context.Clientes
              select c;
 switch (sortOrder)
 {
   case "RazonSocial_desc":
     clientes = clientes.OrderByDescending(s => s.RazonSocial);
     break;
   case "Direccion":
     clientes = clientes.OrderBy(s => s.Direccion);
     break;
   case "Direccion_desc":
     clientes = clientes.OrderByDescending(s => s.Direccion);
     break;
  // case "RUT": //*** asi sucesivamente con otros campos
  //  clientes = clientes.OrderBy(s => s.RUT);
  //  break;
}

int pageSize = 3;
int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
return View(clientes.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}
```

creo que una solución sería algo así, analizalo y comentas si es lo que puede servirte